# Genymotion and v4l2loopback

Tags: genymotion, emulation, v4l2loopback

I would like to use a simulated webcam on Genymotion. I have installed v4l2loopback on my Ubuntu Desktop and it works fine (on a webpage or Cheese) but the camera is not available on Genymotion.

Perhaps because the camera is using a v4l2 driver ? Or is there some precise spec (pixel format, colors ...) to adjust ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I just tried using the DroidCam as a camera but it doesn't worked for me, but  according [this issue](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/127) on the v4l2loopback's repository, the Genymotion have support to v4l2 cameras:

> Under Windows the driver can only be openCV, and it's slow. However
>   under Linux you should be able to use v4l2loopback because we use API
>   v4l2 to read the camera video stream.
>
> So to have a good performance we recommend using Linux with
>   v4l2loopback instead of Windows with openCV, but we cannot guaranty
>   that because have have never conducted any tests on that kind of user
>   case.